# XSLT - How to delete tags and keep content?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I've got an XML file which is something like :

```
<doc>
  <element>
    <word>
      <text>one word</text>
    </word>
    <word>
      <text>two words</text>
    </word>
  </element>
  <element>
    <other>
      <text>the sky</text>
    </other>
    <word>
      <text>NN NN</text>
    </word>
  </element>
</doc>
```

And I'd like to have just one tag  and the content of the lines  when there are two  on after the other, like that :

```
<element>
    <word>
      <text>one word</text>
       <text>two words</text>
    </word>
</element>
```

The problem is that I'm generating an `<xsl:element>` in order to get the `<word>` tags. And this `<xsl:element>` is already in a `<xsl:for-each>` loop that puts the `<word>` tags in the right order (filtering on an attribute).

My previous XML doc is like that :

```
<doc>
  <element class="word">
    <text>one word</text>
  </element>
  <element class="word">
    <text>NN NN</text>
  </element>
  <element class="word">
    <text>two words</text>
  </element>
  <element class="other">
    <text>the sky</text>
  </element>
</doc>
```

Any help would be great, thank you :)

-- More details --

This is the result I want to have :

```
<doc>
   <element>
      <word>
         <text>one word</text>
         <text>two words</text>
      </word>
   </element>
   <element>
      <other>
         <text>the sky</text>
      </other>
      <word>
         <text>NN NN</text>
      </word>
  </element>
</doc>
```

And I can't specify the tags **word** or **other** because I don't have a closed list of tags. So I'm using **xsl:variable** :

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
    <xsl:variable name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
        <text>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </text>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="element/*">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | following-sibling::*[name()=name(current())]/*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It simply looks for any child nodes of `element` that do not have a previous sibling with the same name (i.e., the first of each one), and then applies templates to it's own child nodes and the child nodes of any following siblings with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can "unwrap" an element by just using `<xsl:apply-templates/>`...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <element>
        <word>
            <text>one word</text>
        </word>
        <word>
            <text>two words</text>
        </word>
    </element>
    <element>
        <other>
            <text>the sky</text>
        </other>
        <word>
            <text>NN NN</text>
        </word>
    </element>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:copy>
            <word>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </word>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word|other">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <element>
      <word>
         <text>one word</text>
         <text>two words</text>
      </word>
   </element>
   <element>
      <word>
         <text>the sky</text>
         <text>NN NN</text>
      </word>
   </element>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer ! This is quite what I wanted to do, but my problem is that I can't specify the name of the tags in the match attribute because I get the names of the tags with <xsl:variable>.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="element/*"/>
 <xsl:template match="element/*[1]">
     <word>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../*/*"/>
     </word>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<doc>
    <element>
        <word>
            <text>one word</text>
        </word>
        <word>
            <text>two words</text>
        </word>
    </element>
    <element>
        <other>
            <text>the sky</text>
        </other>
        <word>
            <text>NN NN</text>
        </word>
    </element>
</doc>
```

**produces (what I guess is) the wanted, correct result**:

```
<doc>
   <element>
      <word>
         <text>one word</text>
         <text>two words</text>
      </word>
   </element>
   <element>
      <word>
         <text>the sky</text>
         <text>NN NN</text>
      </word>
   </element>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre for your help ! This result is almost the one I'd like, but I don't to apply the rule if the tags are not the same. In this example, the result might unchange the second <element> part. But I keep searching :) Thank you anyway for your quick answer.

Comment: @user1759737, Sorry, but your comment is incomprehensible. What do you mean by ""I don't to apply the rule if the tags are not the same"? What do you mean by "the result might unchange the second <element> part" ?

Comment: I put more details in the post, I hope this could answer your questions. Thanks you for helping.

Comment: @user1759737, The question, even after the edit, is almost incomprehensible. Please, provide the initial XML document and the final wanted result. Also explain any requirements that the transformation must implement. Don't show us your current half-solution -- you want a solution -- not that any solution must be the same as yours.